# Views: filter by the highest (max) field value of all items

Tags: entities, views

In this case, ‘Volume’ is a text field of type integer. Using the Views module, I want to display only those articles which have the highest value in the volume field.

I am able to do it using contextual filter but I have to provide a default value like 6. Please see the attached screenshot.

Is there any way in views, to detect the highest value of the field and use that as a filter?

[image]

Comment: If you bounty this, I will give you a working solution. There is no way using the views UI, but I know of a workaround solution using php.

Comment: @Suresh Alagar, did you find a solution? I am quite interested if you did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear you will need a subquery for that. You can do that in a custom module.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function MODULE_NAME_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  $max = db_query('select max(YOUR_TABLE_COLUMN) from YOUR_TABLE')->fetchField();
  $query->add_where(0, db_and()->condition('TABLE.YOUR_FIELD_NAME', $max));
}
```

The tricky part here is to create your select query and find the correct field name/alias. Have a look at the query output of your view to find the correct parts.

**Original answer (before clarification)**

Instead of a contextual filter you can use a sort on the 'Volume' field. Sort descending. That way the articles with the highest 'volume' are at the top.

If you want to show only articles with a number higher than X you could add a regular filter for that.

Comment: No, actually my requirement is to show only the list of articles who has highest value in "Volume" filed. Right now the 6 is the highest. So, only top two articles should be shown. 
If the highest is 8, then only the list of articles having 8 in volume should be displayed. Others should not get displayed.

Comment: I changed my answer and your initial question in accordance to your comment. If you need more help you should provide an export of your view and maybe a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I made it in a tricky way.
I created a first view, with just two fields in it: Volume and Issue.
Once hidden both, I rewrited them in a custom text field, in a way like this: <`<p>Magazine nr. [field_issue] / [field_volume]</p>`
Ordered by Volume DESC and Issue DESC. Showing just 1 item. So I have always displayed the last issue.
Then I created another view, to display my articles as I wanted, and I added 2 contextual filters: Volume and Issue.
Finally I embedded the second view in the first as a field, passing from first to second the values of the two fields. So I get the view as attached. Of course if you don't want to display the "Magazine nr. etc." you can hide it by css.[image: screenshot of result]